# In Spritekit, How can automatically resize images according to device

Tags: ios, iphone, sprite-kit

I am newbie in game development,currently I am using the sprite-kit framework. I have added scene on `SKView`. On scene I am setting images to `SKSpriteNode` and building it on iPhone 6 plus simulator, its looking perfect on it,but problem is that, when i build it on lower version like iPhone 5s,4 or 3 ,the some part of images are going outside the simulator screen.I have tried all the scale modes for scene but its not working.

Comment: Well the aspect ratios are not the same so you can't magically scale your game to a different screen size. You need to have a plan. Come up with rules for scaling and positioning nodes using the size of the screen. Some nodes (such as a scrolling world) can simply expand to take advantage of the screen space. Nodes such as UI elements might scale up on larger devices so it looks better. Some nodes might need to be in different spots on the devices when the screen size reaches a certain size. These are special cases you need to check for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the property of `SKScene` called `scaleMode`. You may want to use `SKSceneScaleModeFill` or `SKSceneScaleModeResizeFill`.

More information [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKScene_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/SKSceneScaleMode)